# Mystery status bar icon (handset plus wifi signal indicator)

Tags: notification-icons, samsung-galaxy-s-10

As the title says, does anyone know what this icon means? Just upgraded to a Samsung galaxy s10, but it's not an icon I've seen before. It sits between the wifi and cell signal strength icons.

**Edit/Answer**: To summarise the answer found in the above link, this icon indicates that "wifi calling" is enabled. I've noticed that the icon will appear and disappear depending on how close you are to your router, presumably because the wifi calling feature requires a good signal.

[image]